# Trying to parse JSON with GSON

Tags: java, android, gson

I'm trying to parse a JSON with GSON library on my Android App. I could parse correctly a JSON Array, but now I need to parse another json, with this estructure:

```
    {
    "articles": [
        {
            "article": {
                "articleId": 1,
                "articleName": "Bocadillo de calamares",
                "merchantId": 2,
                "price": 3.5
            },
            "computable": true,
            "orderArticleId": 3157,
            "orderId": 203,
            "price": 3.5,
            "requestedDate": "2012-11-19 13:15:20",
            "shared": true,
            "status": "AS01_INITIAL"
        },
        {
            "article": {
                "articleId": 3,
                "articleName": "Desayuno",
                "merchantId": 2,
                "price": 2.2
            },
            "computable": true,
            "orderArticleId": 3158,
            "orderId": 203,
            "price": 0,
            "requestedDate": "2012-11-19 13:17:30",
            "shared": true,
            "status": "AS01_INITIAL"
        },
        {
            "article": {
                "articleId": 2,
                "articleName": "Café",
                "merchantId": 2,
                "price": 1.1
            },
            "computable": true,
            "orderArticleId": 3156,
            "orderId": 203,
            "price": 1.1,
            "requestedDate": "2012-11-19 13:15:20",
            "shared": true,
            "status": "AS01_INITIAL"
        },
        {
            "article": {
                "articleId": 1,
                "articleName": "Bocadillo de calamares",
                "merchantId": 2,
                "price": 3.5
            },
            "computable": true,
            "orderArticleId": 3155,
            "orderId": 203,
            "price": 3.5,
            "requestedDate": "2012-11-19 12:40:17",
            "shared": true,
            "status": "AS01_INITIAL"
        }
    ],
    "comment": null,
    "creationDate": "2012-11-19 12:06:41",
    "customer": {
        "creationDate": 1353321506000,
        "customerId": 152,
        "devices": [
            {
                "customerId": 152,
                "deviceId": "2000",
                "phone": null
            }
        ],
        "image": false,
        "mail": null,
        "name": null,
        "password": null
    },
    "finishDate": null,
    "group": 0,
    "groupOrders": [],
    "location": {
        "location": "Table 1",
        "locationId": 1,
        "shopId": 2
    },
    "orderId": 203,
    "parentOrderId": 192,
    "score": null,
    "shopId": 2,
    "status": "OS01_INITIAL",
    "ticketUrl": null,
    "tip": null,
    "total": 0,
    "totalArticles": 0,
    "type": "BILL"
}


I have a Order.class like this:

    public class Order {

    private final String orderId;
    (....)
    private final ArrayList<Articles> articles;
    private final String group;


    public Order() {

        orderId = "";
         (....)

        articles = new ArrayList<Articles>();
        group = "";
    }

    public String getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

     (... All getters for each element)

    public ArrayList<Articles> getArticles() {
        return articles;
    }
}
```

And a Articles.class

```
public class Articles {

private final String orderArticleId;
(...)
private final ArrayList<Article> article;

public Articles() {
    orderArticleId = "";
    (....)
    article = new ArrayList<Article>();

};

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

(....All getters for each element)

public ArrayList<Article> getArticle() {
    return article;
}
```

}

And, on my main activity I try to get all the info whith this:

```
    final Gson gson = new Gson();
    Order o = gson.fromJson(jsonData, Order.class);
    System.out.println(" - " +  o.getOrderId() );
```

And works ok, but if I want to get Articles info, the values are null, and I don't know how can I get it.

I try with something like that:

```
 Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<Merchants>>() {
            }.getType();
            data = gson.fromJson(response, collectionType);
```

And I try to use a ArticlesWrapper, but I don't know how to do it exactly.
But I think I forgetting something... and I don't know what.
In another part of the app, I deserialize correctly a JSON because it is an Array, but on this case I don't know how can I get all the data correctly.

If you need more information, I will provide you!.
Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because you are not translating correctly the JSON structure to Java POJOs, basically omitting some fields you have the following structure.

```
+ Order
    + List<BigArticle> articles
    + Customer customer
    + Location location
    + other basic fields

+ BigArticle
    + Article article
    + other basic fields

+ Article
    + basic fields

+ Customer
    + List<Device> devices
    + other basic fields

+ Device
    + basic fields

+ Location
    + basic fields
```

So you should end up with 6 Java POJOs that GSon should be able to populate while deserializing the JSON data.

I just translated your JSON structure to POJO here, and I've let Dates as String to simplify the parsing. If you want to have `java.util.Date` populated correctly you will have to customize the GSon instance.

**Main class**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonData = "...";
        final Gson gson = new Gson();
        Order o = gson.fromJson(jsonData, Order.class);
        System.out.println("orderId: " +  o.getOrderId());
        System.out.println("first article price: " + o.getArticles().get(0).getPrice());
        System.out.println("second article status: " + o.getArticles().get(1).getStatus());
        System.out.println("third article requested date: " + o.getArticles().get(2).getRequestedDate());
    }
}
```

**Order**

```
public class Order {
    private List<BigArticle> articles;
    private String comment;
    private String creationDate;
    private Customer customer;
    private String finishDate;
    private int group;
    private List<Integer> groupOrders;
    private Location location;
    private int orderId;
    private int parentOrderId;
    private int score;
    private int shopId;
    private String status;
    private String ticketUrl;
    private String tip;
    private int total;
    private int totalArticles;
    private String type;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**BigArticle**

```
public class BigArticle {
    private Article article;
    private boolean computable;
    private int orderArticleId;
    private int orderId;
    private double price;
    private String requestedDate;
    private boolean shared;
    private String status;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**Article**

```
public class Article {
    private int articleId;
    private String articleName;
    private int merchantId;
    private double price;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**Customer**

```
public class Customer {
    private long creationDate;
    private int customerId;
    private List<Device> devices;
    private boolean image;
    private String mail;
    private String name;
    private String password;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**Device**

```
public class Device {
    private int customerId;
    private String deviceId;
    private String phone;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**Location**

```
public class Location {
    private String location;
    private int locationId;
    private int shopId;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**Output**

```
orderId: 203
first article price: 3.5
second article status: AS01_INITIAL
third article requested date: 2012-11-19 13:15:20
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks a lot for your answer. I didn't have enough time to tryit, but if works I would give you my whole reputation!! Thanks again.